# Possible to run single Rails command on Heroku without 'heroku run console'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I frequently need to run the command "Rails.cache.clear" on Heroku and the only way I have found to do it is to first run "heroku run console" and then run the command. Any way to do it in one step?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
echo "Rails.cache.clear; exit" | heroku run console
```

Without the exit it seems to hang for some reason, at least for me.

Comment: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/01/18/rails-script-heroku/ points out that you can drop the `;exit` with the `--no-tty` cli param

Answer (score 8):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
heroku run rails runner -e production Rails.cache.clear
```

If you don't set the environment, development will be used.

If it's a common task like clearing the cache, make a rake task.

Comment: upvoted, but I've never needed `-e production`, what you have in Heroku is production.

Comment: What you have in Heroku is determined by the `RAILS_ENV` or `RACK_ENV` environment variables, which are usually set to production.

Answer (score 4):

Create a rake task with the command. For example a file lib/tasks/cache.rake

```
namespace :cache do
  desc 'Clear memcache'
  task :clear => :environment do
    Rails.cache.clear
  end
end
```

Then you can run the command

`heroku run rake cache:clear`